# No server response over IPv6 with NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx, centos, ipv6

I decided I would give IPv6 a go for my website, but I am having issues getting my server to respond to requests via IPv6.

I have already set up an AAAA record and have had a good go at configuring NGINX to respond to requests. My server is running NGINX on CentOS 6.4.

Here is what the top part of my config looks like:

```
    listen      443 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  *.mydomain.net;
    access_log off;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf/ssl-unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf/ssl.key;
```

When I run 'netstat -nlp | grep nginx' I get the following result, as if it is actually listening:

```
tcp        0      0 :::443     :::*                        LISTEN      14463/nginx
```

I've tried quite a few sites that test IPv6 connectivity, like [this one](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php) and [this one](http://ready.chair6.net/), but they all report back as being able to ping the address but get no server response.

All help is highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried connecting locally? What does 'nc -z ::1 443` say? What about actually trying to send a manual `GET / HTTP/1.0` request to it with `nc ::1 443`?

Comment: The netcat command does nothing, no errors or anything.

Comment: Which one? With `-z` it should either return nothing (and an error return code) or print a message about success (and a success return codr).

Comment: My mistake, it's showing a success message.

Comment: If it shows success on port `80` for `::1` (or `::`) but not for `443` then your server isn't listening on `443` on `::` correctly.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, it is displaying a success message for the IPv6.

Comment: Connection to ::1 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!

Comment: Can you connect with openssl? `openssl s_client -connect '[::1]:443'`? What happens if you manually send a get request to that port?

Comment: I can connect via openssl, it prints a load of certificate stuff. A get request returns the index page.

Comment: Then it sounds like things are working correctly. Can you do that from a remote IPV6-enabled host as well?

Comment: Is your firewall open? What is the hostname?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a firewall issue. I do have IPv6, and when I try to `wget` your site:

```
Connecting to **domain** (**domain**)|**IPv6 Address**|:80... failed: Permission denied.
```

The same for HTTPS:

```
Connecting to **domain** (**domain**)|**IPv6 Address**|:443... failed: Permission denied.
```

Likely you only have these open in your IPv4 firewall and not in your IPv6 firewall.

How you fix this depends on your operating system, what web control panels you use, if any, etc. If you're just using CentOS without any control panels you can use the `system-config-network-tui` command line tool to configure your firewall and it will correctly open the ports for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Ah thank you! I didn't realise there was a separate IPtables to edit for IPv6, how daft of me I guess. I did `vi /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables` and added in the ports, appears to be working now!